# Does $E[\epsilon_i | x_i] = 0 \implies E[\epsilon | X] = 0$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Suppose $\epsilon$ and $X$ are random variables, and $\epsilon_i$ and $x_i$ are the $i$-th realizations of these random variables.

Does

$$
E[\epsilon_i|x_i] = 0 \ \ \forall i \implies E[\epsilon | X] = 0
$$

Comment: By $i$th "realization," do you mean component? Are $\epsilon$ and $X$ vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\epsilon_i$ and $x_i$ can be treated as constants, therefore
$$E[\epsilon_i | x_i]=E[\epsilon_i]=\epsilon_i$$
Assuming that $\epsilon_i=0$ and $P(X=x_i)\gt 0$, then
$$E[\epsilon | X]=\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i P(\epsilon=\epsilon_i\vert X=x_i)=0$$

Comment: $E[\epsilon | X]$ is itself technically a random variable, right? It's just we show that it's equal to a constant.